# Error : [an error occurred while processing this directive] and regular expression confusion

Tags: regex, php

I have downloaded a website using ftp , when I test the site in my host , it shows the error

`[an error occurred while processing this directive]`

You can check this error here http://www.excoflare.com/dev2011/amplitechnic/

Also, I am struggle to get a regular expression for a valid floating point number . I used this one :

`expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]/)) return true; else return false;",`

But the above expression returns true even if I write say `1.x` ?

Sorry I put the questions together.

Comment: Why haven't you posted two questions, these two things are completely different!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a web server error:

> Usually, when something goes wrong with your SSI directive, you get the message
>           [an error occurred while processing this directive]

[Apache Tutorial: Introduction to Server Side Includes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/ssi.html)

It is probably caused by something that looks like an SSI directive in you page's code:

```
<!-- Here's the call to the silent-counter script -->
[an error occurred while processing this directive]
<!-------------------------------------------------->
```

SSI directives have the following syntax:

```
<!--#element attribute=value attribute=value ... -->
```

Also, why use regexps when there are specialized functions for determining whether it is a float or not, like is_numeric or is_float (if you need to check variable type) in php.

For jQuery client-side validation you could use JavaScripts parseFloat() function (if it returns NaN, when your input is not a number). 
as suggested here: [jQuery input validation for double/float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542380/jquery-input-validation-for-double-float)

If you want a regexp, you may have a look at this question: [Javascript/jQuery - Float Validating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895760/javascript-jquery-float-validating)

Comment: Thanks for the link Sniff . Server side validation I have done , in the client side I am using jQuery validator,regular expression is for this function on client side .

Comment: I really thought I was running into some strange jquery templating error, alas I just forgot to turn on SSI. Really glad this was the first answer and it involved jQuery for idiots like me.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]
```

Will match the 1 and since you have no end of line anchor $ it matches (partially) your input.

For a better floating point regex you can use this :

```
^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\b$
```

This disregards scientific notation. It matches an integer or a floating point number with optional integer part.  The sign is optional.

If you also want to match scientific notation you can use this :

```
^[-+]?(?:[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+)(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$
```

About the other error I can't help.

Comment: I tried ` expression: "if (VAL.match(/^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\b$/)) return true; else return false;",but it is not accepting any values now !`

Comment: @AssamGuy is your input a number only or does it have more characters?

Comment: Its just an number , only `.` and numbers are allowed

Comment: @AssamGuy It should work. If you could provide some sample input I can see why it doesn't work.